# generate unqie life time random number for each number

Tags: php, algorithm

I had a list of numbers between 1 until 100000000

I need a function  to get a number and return a random number between 1 to 30 For each other number...But unique!

for example each time I call `getrandomnumber('3')` it always return me 25! (no other random number between 1 ...30 like `rand(1,30)`

Comment: `function getrandomnumber($ignore) { return 25; }`, which is [XKCD 221](http://xkcd.com/221/)-compliant.

Comment: Do you suggest me for 1 until 1000000000 write  'return' manually?

Comment: sure, if you want to. or you could show us the actual code that isn't working...

Comment: You want each number from 1 to 100000000 to return a unique numbers, such that for each x,y, x!=y: `rand(x) != rand(y)`, and rand(x),rand(y) are in 1,...,30? That's impossible from pigeonhole principle (unless you allow the generated number to be a floating point number)

Comment: I looking for a function maybe there is a php liberary

Comment: 1- 30 but unique for 100000000 iterations - not sure how that is going to work?

Comment: @MarcB `return 25`. How many dices did you used :D?

Comment: @Dagon The logic on the upper half of the earth is a bit messed up today you know :)

Comment: @Rizier123 under here we are just happy the magnetic shoes stop us falling off!

Comment: I wrote my own solution

Comment: @alirah Then post it as an answer and don't put it into your question

Comment: answer does not match text describing problem - but that's not a surprise. oh its invalid php to

Comment: @Dagon But the 44B449 on the top of your profile is a surprise :) (<- Hope you can figure out what this number means, a little hint: #)

Comment: Now please remove negative scroe! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the given number as a seed and generate the number using the standard random number function.

```
function getrand($num)
{
    srand($num);
    return rand(1 , 30);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Answer**

```
for($i = 0;$i<100;$i++)
echo '<br>'.getrand($i);

function getrand($num)
{
    $num = substr($num, -2);
    $num = (int)$num;
    if($num < 31) return $num;
    elseif($num > 30 && $num < 61) return $num - 30;
    elseif($num > 60 && $num < 91) return $num - 60;
    elseif($num > 90 && $num < 101) return $num - 70;

}
```

Comment: so count to 30 and start again ? no one got that from your question. and this is way overblown to achive it.

Comment: But it is a type of random  function. yes so simple....but works!

Comment: random? how is it random 1-30 repeat

Answer (score 0):

1-30 repeat:

```
$x=0;
for($i = 0;$i<100;$i++){
$x++;
  if($x>30)$x=1;
  echo '<br>'.$x;

}
```